# How Can I Authenticate JWT Before Multipart File Upload With Spring Security?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, keycloak

We have Spring Security set up to use JWTs (issued via Keycloak) - everything works fine except that we have a single endpoint where we upload a `MultiPartFile`

```java
    @PreAuthorize(UserRoles.ADMIN)
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> add(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
        service.add(file);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

The issue is that with some users their JWT expires while the file is uploading and, because the JWT is only checked after, they receive 401 errors even though they have the correct role. Is there any way to check the JWT *before* the file is uploaded? Most issues with this seem to be around CSRF, but we have disabled it anyway. As someone who doesn't delve into Spring Security too often it's not massively obvious to me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `because the JWT is only checked after` this is not true, it even says `PreAuthorize`… pre

Comment: @Toerktumlare It is true as far as I can tell. The file is uploaded, _then_ the authorisation check, _then_ the handler. Yes, authorisation happens before the handler is invoked, but not before the entire file has been uploaded.